# python3 - easiest way to share variable from parent to child using scripts

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, fork

Using script parent.py I would like to set variable `parvar` and execute child.py and have `parvar` printed. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the easiest way to accomplish this. It seems like I could use os.fork() as data present in the parent are presented to the child, but I cannot get it to work. Reading through examples of using multiprocessing I cannot find examples that show sharing data across two different scripts like this.

This is what I have so far:

## parent.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, os
parvar = 'parent var'

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
  print('child pid is running')
  subprocess.call(['python3', 'child.py'])
  exit()
```

## child.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
childvar = 'child var'
print('this is child var: ', childvar)
print(parvar)
```

Which returns a NameError:

```
$ ./parent.py
child pid is running
$ this is child var:  child var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "child.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(parvar)
NameError: name 'parvar' is not defined
```

I think I understand why that is not working. The `subprocess` call replaces the existing process - spawning a new one. Because that was not forked, whatever I made available to my child PID is now inaccessible to that 3rd process.

Can someone help me with a simple example of getting the above to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer (not yet at least) but figured I would post this here since it seems to move things in the right direction.

Using the mmap example from this page:

https://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/

I have (I believe correctly) re-factored it for Python 3 (3.6.8):

## a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
import mmap
import os
import struct


def main():
    # Create new empty file to back memory map on disk
    fd = os.open('/tmp/mmaptest', os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC | os.O_RDWR)

    # Zero out the file to insure it's the right size
    assert os.write(fd, b'\x00' * mmap.PAGESIZE) == mmap.PAGESIZE

    # Create the mmap instace with the following params:
    # fd: File descriptor which backs the mapping or -1 for anonymous mapping
    # length: Must in multiples of PAGESIZE (usually 4 KB)
    # flags: MAP_SHARED means other processes can share this mmap
    # prot: PROT_WRITE means this process can write to this mmap
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd, mmap.PAGESIZE, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_WRITE)

    # Now create an int in the memory mapping
    i = ctypes.c_int.from_buffer(buf)

    # Set a value
    i.value = 10

    # And manipulate it for kicks
    i.value += 1

    assert i.value == 11

    # Before we create a new value, we need to find the offset of the next free
    # memory address within the mmap
    offset = struct.calcsize(i._type_)

    # The offset should be uninitialized ('\x00')
    assert buf[offset] == 0

    # Now ceate a string containing 'foo' by first creating a c_char array
    s_type = ctypes.c_char * len('foo')

    # Now create the ctypes instance
    s = s_type.from_buffer(buf, offset)

    # And finally set it
    s.raw = b'foo'

    print('First 10 bytes of memory mapping: %r' % buf[:10])
    input('Now run b.py and press ENTER')

    print
    print('Changing i')
    i.value *= i.value

    print('Changing s')
    s.raw = b'bar'

    new_i = input('Enter a new value for i: ')
    i.value = int(new_i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## b.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mmap
import os
import struct
import time

def main():
    # Open the file for reading
    fd = os.open('/tmp/mmaptest', os.O_RDONLY)

    # Memory map the file
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd, mmap.PAGESIZE, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)

    i = None
    s = None

    while 1:
        new_i, = struct.unpack('i', buf[:4])
        new_s, = struct.unpack('3s', buf[4:7])

        if i != new_i or s != new_s:
            print('i: %s => %d' % (i, new_i))
            print('s: %s => %s' % (s, new_s))
            print('Press Ctrl-C to exit')
            i = new_i
            s = new_s

        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Execution Example

#### terminal 1

```
$ ./a.py
First 10 bytes of memory mapping: b'\x0b\x00\x00\x00foo\x00\x00\x00'
Now run b.py and press ENTER
Changing i
Changing s
Enter a new value for i: 87
```

#### terminal 2

```
$ ./b.py
i: None => 11
s: None => b'foo'
Press Ctrl-C to exit
i: 11 => 121
s: b'foo' => b'bar'
Press Ctrl-C to exit
i: 121 => 87
s: b'bar' => b'bar'
Press Ctrl-C to exit
```